# Downloading all the available Android versions using Single link to install offline

Tags: android

is there any link available to download all the Android versions including Google API's?.If there is, can you please provide the link?.

Answer (score 1):

Query http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml

As you can see this is all versions google has published, so replace "repository.xml" with the sdk:url tags and you will download this sdk, for example for download "android-17_r01.zip" just use http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-17_r01.zip

Comment: Actually iam just behind proxy.There is no option to me to download.I need to handover the url to my companies downloading team.In this case i cannot give multiple urls,i would like to give only single url.Thank you very much for giving some idea.

Comment: You can download all sdks, compress it in one file and re-upload to your server, I think there is no option to download with just one link. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Installing offline android requirement has very problem ,download android sdk then run sdk manager ,it provides everything you need.